Buffering with a barrier in ArcGIS Pro?
Not sure if this is possible but I'm looking to buffer streets (black lines) and I want the buffer to stop at the edge of these parcels (pink). Is this possible?


Buffer, then Union, then Select By Attributes, and FeatureClassToFeatureClass.

Buffer then Pairwise Erase.

will try those, thanks!

There is no direct method. If the pink parcels are polygons, after processing the buffer you can make a crop using these polygons
